# Dynamically adjust position of Button in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have a Button in Linear Layout when I see in the Design view of Activity xml ,it looks like it is perfectly positioned but when I see in GenyMotoin avd it is farly placed from what I expected.
How to dynamically adjust the position of button on different screen sizes?

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.xxx.MainScreen"
    android:background="#b6b6b6">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="263dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="264dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next Act"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: and your questions is?

Comment: 1. Please be specific about your problem.
2. Post your xml file.
3. What are you wanted to achieve and what are you getting now?

Comment: what have you done till now ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Linear Layout for the outermost layout.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your trying to achieve but If you want to position your views at the center on all devices. Try to use [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) instead of [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#b6b6b6"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.offtogeek.motivatemyself.MainScreen">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Next Quote" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```